# How to find the issue type in jira with issue id

Tags: jira, confluence

I have one issue id. TP-176. I want to know whether it is technical task or bug or story or improvement. What method should use from API. Can any one suggest me.

Comment: which version of JIRA is that?

Comment: Sorry I dont know the version

Comment: How to find the version? May be this is another question :)

Comment: do you have access to the JIRA instance? if you don't have - ask those who have.

Comment: You'll find it at the bottom of the screen, for example: (v4.4.4#664-r167664)

Answer (score 5):

### Java API

How about `issue.getIssueType()`

Jira Java API [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getIssueType%28%29)

### REST API

Get the issue JSON: http://jira.server.com/rest/api/latest/issue/PROJECT-1
Path to the issuetype in the JSON: `fields.issuetype`

Jira REST API [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp1850528)